# Showing Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous when trying to get data from many to many relationship laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get data from m2m relational table, using this query. Here is my code in model:

User.php

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Role.php

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'role_user', 'role_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

and my query in controller is:

```
$userDetails = Role::where('role_id', $roleId)->first()
            ->users()
            ->select('user_id', 'full_name', 'phone_no')
            ->where('is_active', 1)
            ->get();
```

But it is showing `Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous`. After searching solution in online i found some suggestion that to prefix table name like this `users.user_id` while selecting the table name. But it is showing `Unknown column users.user_id`. can anyone help me out with that.

Comment: How are you adding the table name in `users.user_id`?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova ->select('users.user_id', 'full_name', 'phone_no') like this

Comment: change `>select('user_id'..` to `>select('roles.user_id'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'user_id'` in field list **is ambiguous** means `user_id` column is persent in your both tables.

You have to specify which table `user_id` you want to use in your query.

**Change**

```
->select('user_id', 'full_name', 'phone_no')
```

**to**

```
->select('roles.user_id', 'full_name', 'phone_no')
```

Comment: tried that too... still  not working `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.user_id, full_name, phone_no' `

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed what is your table name which contains user_id?

Comment: tbl_users, tbl_roles.. And i tried prefixing both of them.. Not working..

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention the solution.. Yes your solution kinda right. But the problem was i was using relation name (roles, users) from model, But it should be actual table name. My table name was tbl_roles. Thats what causing the problem. Thanks for your contribution. I will accept yours as correct answer. But you should also edit your answer and point out this scenario for future developer who might face the same problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As @Sehdev states:

> 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous means user_id column is persent in your both tables.
>
> You have to specify which table user_id you want to use in your query.

This is a standard SQL error which can be fixed by being explicit as to which table the colum n belongs like so:

```
'roles.user_id'
```

---

**Eloquent Relationships**

I thought it worthwhile to point out that the queries you are doing can be carried out using `Eloquent` like so:

```
$role = Role::find('role_id', $roleId)->with(['users' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('is_active', 1);
}]);
```

You can then use these in your controller as you wish by simply accessing the `users` relationship on the role like so:

```
$role->users
```

Or in a blade template like so:

```
@foreach ($role->users as $user)
    {{ $user->user_id }}
    {{ $user->fullname }}
    {{ $user->phone_no }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: @why it is not working when i'm using users.user_id!

Comment: it is not working `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.user_id, full_name, phone_no' `